# webview hyperlink opening in default web browser

Tags: android, jsp

I have a android app which contains jsp page.
On this jsp page one hyperlink is created and linked another jsp page which contains download pdf code.

When I click on hyperlink it will open in android default browser and download starts.

I want to download pdf inside web view without opening web browser.

Comment: "a android app which contains jsp page" ???

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use like this:
Every time you click a link WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading method will be called. Check that url points to pdf file and do what you want. For example, you can view pdf.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
        // if want to download pdf manually create AsyncTask here
        // and download file
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Yes. But hyperlink url not ends with .Pdf it ends with .Jsp. hyperlink is as below <a href="DownloadPdf.jsp" > Download Pdf </a>

Comment: If possible then, please share your PDF URL. So, I can easily understand.

Comment: when Download Pdf clicked pdf download starts but on the mobile default web browser Not in android web view.

Comment: <a href="DownloadPdf.jsp" > Download Pdf </a>  is hyperlink and on this "DownloadPdf.jsp" download pdf code written.

Comment: Yes, it's because of the android device have multiple browsers installed on it then they by default ask the user to which app they want to use.

Comment: If device have only one browser then they don't give you any choise.

Comment: So, don't worry about that, and if your url ends or contains .pdf then use my above given code.

Comment: So, if you satisfied with my answer you can vote up and make right on my given answer. Thank's.

Comment: Thanks Hemant. After detailed analysis i identified the exact issue.
when content type of DownloadPdf.jsp is application/pdf then it is not loading. 
so could you share the logic of 
How to load/render url with content type application/pdf in webview?